# Can't upload Sketch to Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have tried to upload a sketch to one of my Arduino Nano, but unfortunately, I can't upload. The IDE showing uploading for a long time.

- Board: Nano
- IDE: 1.8.5
- Processor: ATmega380p
- Port: Tried 3 of my laptop port (COM3,COM4, COM5)
- Programmer: AVRISP mkll

The other one is working fine, So I am suspecting this is a board issue. So how can I test to reset to the newborn?

Is there any static damage happened to the board? How to test or reset to the newborn?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you on ? What's the serial port name (Does it show up?) Is it a legit Arduino Nano or a Chinese clone ?

Comment: I am trying in windows, the ports are COM4, COM3 and I don't know is it an original or fake

Comment: Did you install CH340 driver?

Comment: @Godwin you should have 1 port for 1 Arduino. Try unplugging the arduino and see what COM ports are left (maybe your computer has an internal serial port). This way you can isolate which COM port is the Arduino to set in Arduino. If you've got a fake as dzuda mentions install the CH340 driver: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Nano-CH340/ Images will help discern which board you've got. The legit version uses the FTDI Chip serial converter AFAIK in which case install https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm In short: make sure you talk to the right COM port, and the driver is installed

Comment: But in my case, another one is uploading and working fine.